# Convert Number to Array without for loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I very simply convert an `number` into an `array` without doing a *for loop*?

Something like this:

```
var days = 30;
var days = days.toArray(); // Output - [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...]
```

What I currently do is following:

```
var days = 30;
```

```js
var days = 30;
var array = [];

for(var i = 1;i <= 30;i++) {
  array.push(i);
}

console.log(array);
```

Comment: 2.5K rep and no searching SO for something? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+array+create+range+integers

Comment: Some people just ain't so good searching as others. I don't even know what the `range` method stand for. Now I do though. I was searching like so on SO and google: `convert number to array` and `convert number to array without loop`.

Comment: no need to reinvent the wheel https://github.com/Gothdo/range

Comment: OK I agree my google-fu is excellent :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

> `Array.from()` has an optional parameter `mapFn`, which allows you to execute a `map` function on each element of the array (or subclass object) that is being created. More clearly, `Array.from(obj, mapFn, thisArg)` has the same result as `Array.from(obj).map(mapFn, thisArg)`, except that it does not create an intermediate array.

Try `Array.from()` by passing an object with length property as the first parameter and map function as the second parameter:

```js
var days = 30;
var days = Array.from({length: days}, (v, i) => i+1);
console.log(days)
```

Comment: This did it for me (taken from the duplicate) `var array = [...Array(30]`

Comment: suggestion: `i+1`, to let your answer exactly the same as asker desired result :D

Comment: Nvm, I take your anwser as this is supported in IE aswell, thanks! :)

Comment: @Red, you are most welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use spread syntax.

Reference Document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

```js
array = [...Array(30).keys()]
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Starts at 0 not 1